# Erro ao tentar criar uma migration no laravel

Tags: php, mysql, banco-de-dados, laravel

Acabei de criar um novo projeto em laravel, porém na hora de criar uma migration, porém ocorre um erro no banco de dados.

Ja tentei criar uma nova database ou utilizar uma já existente, mas o problema continua.

### Segue o erro que estou tendo

```
 Illuminate\Database\QueryException  : SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'homestead'@'localhost' (using password: YES) (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = homestead and table_name = migrations and table_type = 'BASE TABLE')
```

---

```
PDOException::("SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'homestead'@'localhost' (using password: YES)")
      /home/pc-root/Área de Trabalho/laravel/blog/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connectors/Connector.php:70
```

---

```
PDO::__construct("mysql:host=127.0.0.1;port=3306;dbname=homestead", "homestead", "secret", [])
      /home/pc-root/Área de Trabalho/laravel/blog/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connectors/Connector.php:70
```

---

Gostaria de saber como posso resolver este problema.

Comment: o arquivo .env  está configurado com o nome do BD, usuário e senha?

Comment: Sim...  com os mesmos dados apresentados acima.

Comment: O banco de dados não existe ainda... já deveria existir quando se cria o projeto?

Comment: Conseguiu resolver seu problema?

Comment: Verifique se o usuário destinado a usar o banco tem as permissões corretas de acesso, inclusive dependendo do ambiente é necessário estabelecer os hosts de acesso ao banco. [Veja este exemplo](https://zemez.io/magento/support/how-to/create-new-database-database-user-grant-permissions-ssh/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1- Crie o banco de dados,

2 - Este são os arquivos do seu projeto:

[image: Arquivos da instalação Laravel]

3 - Abra o arquivo .env verifique se os dados do banco de dados estão corretamente configurados.
Caso estiver usando o mysql fica assim.

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=NomeDoBanco
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=NormalmenteSemSenha
```

normalmente se for Localhost o usuário é root e não tem senha, mas ai já varia conforme você criou.

Apos conectado tente rodar sua Migration